# NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED while navigating to localhost:8000 in Playwright on Azure pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, azure-pipelines, localhost, playwright

I am currently trying to get some Playwright unit tests in a .NET solution on a Azure pipeline. The tests all run locally on my machine. However on in the Azure pipeline, the tests fail.

Within the test assembly, it successfully register localhost:8000

Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:8000/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/"
Registration completed
IIS Express is running.

However, when it tries to access the url for a unit test I get the following exception thrown by Playwright

**Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "http://localhost:8000/Operations/Home", waiting until "load"
============================================================**

Stack Trace:
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.d__34`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 143 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.<WrapApiCallAsync>d__44`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Playwright.Core.Frame.d__91.MoveNext() in /_/src/Playwright/Core/Frame.cs:line 547
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Company.UITest.Account.SemanticsAnalyticsTest.d__2.MoveNext() in D:\a\93\s\Main\Company.UITest\Account\SemanticsAnalyticsTest.cs:line 65
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Company.UITest.Account.SemanticsAnalyticsTest.d__2.MoveNext() in D:\a\93\s\Main\Company.UITest\Account\SemanticsAnalyticsTest.cs:line 78
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
Standard Output Messages:
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /path:"D:\a\93\s\Main\Company" /port:8000

Tried the URL as google.com
Tried localhost:8000 with http and https
Tried http://localhost:8000/Operations/Home

Expected homepage to load and the test to confirm that the url was reached

Answer (score 0):

try running azure pipeline using a self hosted agent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops